# With Firebase realtime database, do I still need to use flux, redux, mobx or relay with graphql

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, graphql, relay

Sorry in advance for a stupid question, perhaps. I cannot understand, with Firebase realtime database, do I still need to use flux, redux, mobx or relay with graphql? If so, where are they fit?

Comment: That's an incredibly broad question! Why do you think you would need a third party tool - what purpose would they serve? What's the use case? Please see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I am still learning all these technologies. I do not have any specific needs at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

GraphQL is a query language based on an open specification, so there are no required tools to use it. You can use any client that's HTTP capable. Using GraphQL in combination with [MobX](https://github.com/graphcool-examples/react-lokka-mobx-todo-example) and [Redux](https://github.com/graphcool-examples/react-apollo-todo-example) is also an option.

With the recent [RFC regarding GraphQL subscriptions](https://github.com/facebook/graphql/pull/267), GraphQL is also a good answer for your realtime needs. Here's a [live demo](https://demo.graph.cool/worldchat) for GraphQL subscriptions and [the corresponding video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aSLF9f13o2c) to get a better understanding of the underlying concepts.

To get started with GraphQL, you should check out [Graphcool](https://graph.cool) that combines serverless functions like [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) with the strengths of GraphQL to offer a flexible database that's also realtime capable.

Disclaimer: I work at Graphcool :)

Answer (score 1):

The firebase SDK will handle a lot of what these tools provide. That being said there is always a spot for something like redux in terms of maintaining application state outside of the network layer.

If you know that you want to use GraphQL there are real-time GraphQL BaaS platforms like https://scaphold.io that will integrate more seamlessly with the modem JS stack. With these platforms you will see performance increases with client caching libraries like relay and Apollo client.

Here is a tutorial if you are interested: https://scaphold.io/blog/2016/11/09/build-realtime-apps-with-subs.html